# Storing Login information of user using spring MVC and LDAP

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-mvc, authentication, ldap

I am using LDAP for authentication and want to store login name and some relevant details of user. I am using spring MVC to connect to LDAP. So i want to get information from LDAP and store it in my serve based postgres DB. I couldnot find any relevant or proper example of how to do this???? An example project would be greatly helpful. Thank you .